Sorting by eventdate instead of date through sourcemapping
I need to sort the bibliography by eventdate instead of date, only for one specific type entry,

using the biber sourcemapping;
without creating custom sort templates.

Below a wme:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@customa{test1,
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {Title of the custom entrytype},
  eventdate = {2024-01-02},
}
@customa{test2,
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {Title of the custom entrytype},
  eventdate = {2024-01-01},
}
@article{test3,
  author = {Smith, Arthur},
  title = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journaltitle},
  date = {2022},
}
@article{test4,
  author = {Smith, Arthur},
  title = {Title},
  journaltitle = {Journaltitle},
  date = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false,sorting=ndt}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{customa}
      \step[fieldsource=eventdate, final, match=\regexp{\A(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\Z}]
      \step[fieldset=sortyear, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=month, fieldvalue={$2}]
      \step[fieldset=day, fieldvalue={$3}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareLabeldate[customa]{%
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printeventdate%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\textcite{test1,test2,test3,test4}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Sorting occurs correctly only at the year/month level, but not at the day level.
I suspect that the problem is the same as this issue.
How can this be solved without creating a custom sorting template?
PS: The regexp is intentionally simplified for the wme.
